# Сайт не загружается, при использовании прокси

Tags: proxy, steam

Пытаясь зайти на сайт (https://steamcommunity.com/) через прокси, у меня он просто не загружается. Без прокси же всё работает. Такое поведение сайта означает, что адрес прокси в бане?

Comment: Только он не загружается?

Comment: да только он не грузит

Comment: Нужны логи, трассировка, пинги....